# How can I get an Azure AD users MFA state using the AzureAD module?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-core

It seems that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#change-state-using-powershell) refers to using the `MSOnline` module which however is outdated and got replaced by `AzureAD`. The problem I am facing is that `MSOnline` is not compatible with `PowerShell Core`, which is a requirement in my case.

So long story short: How can I retrieve the  MFA state of a user using `PowerShell Core` and the `AzureAD` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not support getting the MFA state with `AzureAD` module in PowerShell. Only MSOnline can be used except the portal.

Please refer to the [similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10926) and this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20249953-powershell-and-graph-api-support-for-managing-mult). There are APIs are used to manage a user's authentication methods, but no method able to get their MFA registration status.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.